# grepping using the result of previous grep

Tags: linux, grep

Is there a way to perform a grep based on the results of a previous grep, rather than just piping multiple greps into each other. For example, say I have the log file output below:

```
ID 1000 xyz occured
ID 1001 misc content
ID 1000 misc content
ID 1000 status code: 26348931276572174
ID 1000 misc content
ID 1001 misc content
```

To begin with,  I'd like to grep the whole log file file to see if "xyz occured" is present. If it is, I'd like to get the ID number of that event and grep through all the lines in the file with that ID number looking for the status code.

I'd imagined that I could use xargs or something like that but I can't seem to get it work.

```
grep "xyz occured" file.log | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs grep "status code" | awk '{print $NF}'
```

Any ideas on how to actually do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost there.  But while xargs can sometimes be used to do what you want (depending on how the next command takes its arguments), you aren't actually using it to grep for the ID you just extracted.  What you need to do is take the output of the first grep (containing the ID code) and use that in the next grep's expression.  Something like:

```
grep "^ID `grep 'xyz occured' file.log | awk '{print $2}'` status code" file.log
```

Obviously another option would be to write a script to do this in one pass, a-la Ed's suggestion.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 29):

A general answer for grep-ing the grep-ed output:

```
grep 'patten1' *.txt | grep 'pattern2'
```

notice that the second grep is not pointing at a file.

More about cool grep stuff [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/)

Comment: Why doesn't `grep --help | grep help` work? (grepping the output of `grep --help`)

Comment: It does work. (I use the gnome-terminal and grep-ing the help page returns the expected lines)

Comment: Should this be expected to work in Cygwin Bash? Because it's not working for me. When I run the first grep by itself, it outputs a list of paths and filenames on separate lines. When I add the second grep, which I know matches several lines in several of the listed files, it returns no results.

Comment: This would not help the OP and is not what he asked for.

Answer (score 3):

This is all about retrieve the files in a narrowed search scope. In your case the search scope is determined by a file content.

I have found this problem more often while reducing the search scope through many searches (applying filters to the previous grep results).

**Trying to find general answer**:

1. Generate a list with the result of the first grep:

   grep pattern | awk -F':' '{print $1}'
2. Second grep into the list of files like [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178857/grep-files-from-list)

   xargs grep -i pattern
3. apply this cascading filter the times you need just adding awk to get only the filenames and `xargs` to pass the filenames to  `grep -i`

For example:

```
grep 'pattern1' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' | xargs grep -i 'pattern2'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way

```
for x in `grep "xyz occured" file.log | cut -d\  -f2`
do
  grep $x file.log
done
```

The thing I like about this method is if you wanted to you could write the output to a file for each status code.

```
grep $x file.log >> /var/tmp/$x.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
awk '{info[$2] = info[$2] $0 ORS} /xyz occured/{ids[$2]} END{ for (id in ids) printf "%s",info[id]}' file.log
```

or:

```
awk '/status code/{code[$2]=$NF} /xyz occured/{ids[$2]} END{ for (id in ids) print code[id]}' file.log
```

depending what you really want to output. Some expected output in your question would help.

Comment: In that case the expected output would just be the actual status code. In reality, the log file are much more complex and would need regex greps but I've simplified it for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Whatever the reality of your log file format is, you can still do it with just one awk command. Post another question with some truly representative input and expected output if you'd like to do that.

Answer (score 1):

**Grep the result of a previous Grep:**

Given this file contents:

```
ID 1000 xyz occured
ID 1001 misc content
ID 1000 misc content
ID 1000 status code: 26348931276572174
ID 1000 misc content
ID 1001 misc content
```

This command:

```
grep "xyz" file.log | awk '{ print $2 }' > f.log; grep `cat f.log` file.log;
```

returns this:

```
ID 1000 xyz occured
ID 1000 misc content
ID 1000 status code: 26348931276572174
ID 1000 misc content
```

It looks for "xyz" in file.log places the result in f.log.  Then greps for that ID in file.log.  If the outer grep returns multiple ID numbers, then the inner grep will only search the first ID number and error out on the others.

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping to be able to do it without creating an extra files if that's possible.

Comment: you can easily remove the file after each command: `grep "xyz" file.log | awk '{ print $2 }' > f.log; grep \`cat f.log\` file.log; rm f.log `